# Declaring variables of same type and reusing them

Tags: c++, crypto++

I have the following scenario and was wondering if there is a good solution for it.

I am using [Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/) and declare the following:

```
if (_HashType == SHA1)
{
    PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC<CryptoPP::SHA1> pbkdf;
    pbkdf.DeriveKey(...)
}
else if (_HashType == SHA256)
{
    PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC<CryptoPP::SHA256> pbkdf;
    pbkdf.DeriveKey(...)
}
else if (_HashType == SHA384)
{
    PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC<CryptoPP::SHA384> pbkdf;
    pbkdf.DeriveKey(...)
}
else if (_HashType == SHA512)
{
    PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC<CryptoPP::SHA512> pbkdf;
    pbkdf.DeriveKey(...)
}
```

what I would like to do is something like this:

```
PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC<?> pbkdf;     
if (_HashType == SHA1)
    PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC<CryptoPP::SHA1> pbkdf;
else if (_HashType == SHA256)
    PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC<CryptoPP::SHA256> pbkdf;
else if (_HashType == SHA384)
    PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC<CryptoPP::SHA384> pbkdf;
else if (_HashType == SHA512)
    PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC<CryptoPP::SHA512> pbkdf;

pbkdf.DeriveKey(...)
```

Any advice?

Comment: Each of those `pbkdf` are a *different type*. You can't do it like that.

Comment: does PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC have a common base class? is it yours or a library (can you change it?)

Comment: @Adviner - Also see [Chain-of-responsibility pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) and [Strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). (I think they are patterns that might help you here).

Comment: Thanks jww I will take a look at it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common base class for `PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC<>` is [`PasswordBasedKeyDerivationFunction`](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_password_based_key_derivation_function.html), so what you can do is:

```
PasswordBasedKeyDerivationFunction* pbkdf;     
if (_HashType == SHA1)
    pbkdf = new PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC<CryptoPP::SHA1>();
else if (_HashType == SHA256)
    pbkdf = new PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC<CryptoPP::SHA256>();
else if (_HashType == SHA384)
    pbkdf = new PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC<CryptoPP::SHA384>();
else if (_HashType == SHA512)
    pbkdf = PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC<CryptoPP::SHA512>();

pbkdf->DeriveKey(...)    

//...
delete pbkdf;
```

If you are using C++11 or later, you can use smart pointers and don't have to worry about memory management:

```
std::unique_ptr<PasswordBasedKeyDerivationFunction> pbkdf;     

if (_HashType == SHA1)
    pbkdf.reset(new PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC<CryptoPP::SHA1>());
else if (_HashType == SHA256)
    pbkdf.reset(new PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC<CryptoPP::SHA256>());
else if (_HashType == SHA384)
    pbkdf.reset(new PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC<CryptoPP::SHA384>());
else if (_HashType == SHA512)
    pbkdf.reset(PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC<CryptoPP::SHA512>());

pbkdf->DeriveKey(...)
```

Comment: While possible, this isn’t a very good solution in this specific case. Reserve dynamic dispatch for where it’s needed and use static dispatch otherwise.

Comment: @KonradRudolph sure, but we don't know if `_HashType` is a runtime variable or compile time constant

Comment: Doesn’t matter in this case. You can always call a separate function with the respective type.

Comment: @KonradRudolph could you please illustrate your approach in more detail?

Comment: `if (foo) use_pbkdf<CryptoPP::SHA1>(); else if (bar) use_pbkdf<CryptoPP::SHA256>() else if (baz) …;`

Comment: @m.s.  I really like your solution especially the smart pointer version.  Thank you

Comment: @m.s, *"If you are using C++11 or later..."* - Crypto++ offers `member_ptr`, which overloads `operator->`. It avoids the switching needed to support both `auto_ptr` and `unique_ptr`. It might help Adviner *if* ownership is not a concern. See the documentation for [`member_ptr< T >`](http://cryptopp.com/docs/ref/classmember__ptr.html).